# The number of different minimal cover possible are?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema, functional-dependencies

> Consider R(A,B,C,D,E,F,G) be a relational schema with the following functional dependencies:
>   AC->G, D->EG, BC->D, CG->BD, ACD->B, CE->AG. The number of different minimal cover possible are___________?

Actually in this question we were supposed to find all the possible minimal covers. I used [this](https://youtu.be/IiEAfRoHIH8?t=2m17s) video 
So using that theory i tried doing this question but end up getting only 2 minimal covers and then answer given in my text book is 4 .
The minimal covers I got are:

> 1)
>   D->E,D->G,BC->D,CG->D,AC->B(#),CE->A
>
> 2)
>   AC->G,D->E,D->G,BC->D,CG->D,CD->B(#),
>   CE->A

Actually the video gives only standard procedure to FIND a minimal cover. but the problem is a bit tricky as it asks about how MANY minimal covers we can find. I am applying the algorithm right...the only issue is that I am unable to find how many more minimal covers can be possible for the given set of FD's

Comment: Put everything necessary to ask your question in your post--including definitions & procedures. (A "basically" or "essentially" or "in other words" that doesn't introduce or summarize a clear, precise & full description that you also give just means "unclearly".) Phrasing like "go alone and is not needing" is not clear, use technical terms. PS You are told certain FDs hold. So certain others do. But it's not given whether yet others do or don't, and one needs to know *all* FDs that hold to determine minimal covers. So probably your instructor is giving a cover--but that's not what they say.

Comment: This is still not clear. What is a "left extraneous attribute"? What are "closure gives" & "is extra"? Why does what mean that you have 2 choices? Use enough words & sentences to clearly & fully say what you mean. PS If you have an algorithm & you are following it then I can imagine that you got the algorithm wrong & end up with a wrong answer but what do you mean you are struggling? PS Your profile says you are a student. What is the exact algorithm as given in your textbook or handout?

Comment: See basically I wanted all the possible minimal covers of the following functional dependencies: AC->G, D->EG, BC->D, CG->BD, ACD->B, CE->AG and I could only find 2 of them ...but my book gives 4 as answer...

Comment: You may even use any other method...but at least can you help me get 4 minimal covers..for this problem...(and if there any better method exists then do consider sharing ..)

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Re "basically" see my 1st comment. PS Your problem is that you are not getting and/or not following the algorithm you are supposed to follow. If you can't explain your algorhtm clearly how do you expect to follow it or ask for help? (Rhetorical.) If you want other methods, research & ask a question where stuck. See [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common algorithm to produce a minimal cover consists of three steps:

1. Split the right part, producing FDs with only one attribute on the right part.
2. For each left part with more than one attribute, try to remove each attribute in turn and see if the remaining can still determine the right part. In this case, eliminate the attribute from the left part.
3. For each remaining dependency, try to see if it can be eliminated.

In your case the first step produces:

```
F = { A C → G
      A C D → B
      B C → D
      C G → B
      C G → D
      C E → A
      C E → G
      D → E
      D → G }
```

In the second step, we must check the first seven dependencies. For each dependency `A1A2...An -> B` we try to eliminate in turn each `Ai` and see
if `B` is included in the closure of the remaining attributes (the closure taken with respect to F). In this case we have two possibilities: from `ACD -> B` we can eliminate either `A` or `D`. So we have now two different set of dependencies:

```
F1 = { A C → G
       C D → B
       B C → D
       C G → B
       C G → D
       C E → A
       C E → G
       D → E
       D → G }
```

and

```
F2 = { A C → G
       A C → B
       B C → D
       C G → B
       C G → D
       C E → A
       C E → G
       D → E
       D → G }
```

Now we can apply the last step: for each dependency `X -> A` we can see if `A` is included in the closure of `X`, `X+` with respect to all the other dependencies. In this case, we can eliminate that dependency.

The result will depend, in general, from the order in which we apply those checks.

Here there are four different canonical covers:

```
G1 = { A C → G
       B C → D
       C G → B
       C E → A
       D → E
       D → G }

G2 = { A C → G
       B C → D
       C G → D
       C E → A
       C D → B
       D → E
       D → G }

G3 = { A C → B
       B C → D
       C G → B
       C E → A
       D → E
       D → G }

G4 = { A C → B
       B C → D
       C G → D
       C E → A
       D → E
       D → G }
```

Note: it is not clear to me if there are other canonical covers.

Comment: Okay thank you sir for your efforts ...now I actually got how to approach this problem...and where I was committing a mistake...and I'll surely try to find if any more I can get by applying those checks..

Comment: @Renzo, sir is it necessary that the minimal cover will have last number of FDs or it can vary? In the example you've solved above there are 2 covers of size 6 and one of size 7. Which one will be the minimal cover?

Comment: @deadpool, There are several different terminologies that are used to describe canonical covers. One of them is “minimal”, and it is used for covers which are not only canonical but also with the smaller number of FD and of attributes of the FD. But in general for the theorems and the algorithms of the theory it is sufficient to have a canonical cover, not necessarily minimal.